# Cannon's Algorithm for Matrix Multiplication with small number of processors

Tags: algorithm, matrix, matrix-multiplication

While researching Cannon's algorithm, there are always examples of the same kind. For example if the size of matrix A and B is 3x3;  there are always 9 processor in the examples. Each processor is responsible for its cell and adds the value to the sum. Also the instructions always have the same "Process P(i , j) initially stores A(i , j) and B(i , j) computes block C(i , j) of the result matrix" expression.

I understand this case. I put an example case below. These are the initial matrixes.

[image: Initial]

And this is the position of processors;

[image]

As in this example I put in, the number of processors has always been chosen to deal with only the 1x1 part of the matrix. I wonder what the situation would have been if the number of processors were not chosen like this, but in a way that each processor would deal with more parts.

However, what would happen if 4 processors were used to multiply 4x4 matrices? As I understood from the instructions, each process would take the 2x2 parts of the A and B matrix. In other words, as in the picture I put below, the 1st process would keep the elements of the A and B matrix in the indices (0,0), (0,1), (1,0) (1,1). Second process would keep the indexes of (0,2), (0,3), (1,2) and (1,3).

[image]

What would changing the number of processes change about the communication situations or the number of steps required to complete the algorithm? For example, would you have to do more shifts with each step?

Comment: You would first need to specify *how* the algorithm would make use of those extra processors.

Comment: I'm not talking about adding an extra processor. In classical Cannon's matrix multiplication algorithm, I am talking about using less number of processors, not NxN number of processors.

Comment: You still need to explain *how* you are going to deviate from the algorithm, whether you are using more or fewer processors than the algorithm requires.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdRm0.jpg

As in the instructions in the picture, p is a parameter value, which is actually the number of the processor. The algorithm changes dynamically according to the number of processors. I do not make any modifications.